# how to hide TextBox based on checkbox in kivy

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

## test.py

```
import sqlite3 as lite

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (600, 325)

class UserGroup(Screen):
    pass


class FactUserGroup(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FactUserGroup().run()
```

## test.kv

```
<CustomLabel@Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5

<SingleLineTextInput@TextInput>:
    multiline: False

<GreenButton@Button>:
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.parent.height * 0.120

UserGroup

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        padding : 30,30
        spacing: 20, 20
        row_default_height: '30dp'

        Label:
            text: 'Male'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'middle'

        CheckBox:
            group: 'check'
            id : chk


        Label:
            text: 'Female'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'middle'

        CheckBox:
            group: 'check'

        CustomLabel:
            text: 'age'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'middle'

        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: age


        GreenButton:
            text: 'Ok'


        GreenButton:
            text: 'Cancel'
            on_press: app.stop()
```

I am new to python/kivy.I don't have any idea how checkbox works?
 How to Hide,show 'Age' textbox,label according male,female checkbox.
If i select Male then Age textbox and label should be show.If i select female then Age textbox and label should be remove.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use ***opacity*** property to hide the widget. By default opacity is set to ***1*** meaning visible, and ***0*** meaning invisible. I have also used ObjectProperty to hook up to the age Label widget,and TextInput widget. Please refer to the example for details.

```
widget.opacity = 0    # invisible
```

## Example

### test.py

```
import sqlite3 as lite

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (600, 325)


class UserGroup(Screen):
    age_label = ObjectProperty(None)
    age_textinput = ObjectProperty(None)


class FactUserGroup(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FactUserGroup().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<CustomLabel@Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5

<SingleLineTextInput@TextInput>:
    multiline: False

<GreenButton@Button>:
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.parent.height * 0.120

UserGroup:
    age_label: age_label
    age_textinput: age

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        padding : 30,30
        spacing: 20, 20
        row_default_height: '30dp'

        Label:
            text: 'Male'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'middle'

        CheckBox:
            id : chk
            group: 'check'
            on_active:
                root.age_label.opacity=1    # Visible
                root.age_textinput.opacity=1    # Visible

        Label:
            text: 'Female'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'middle'

        CheckBox:
            group: 'check'
            on_active:
                root.age_label.opacity=0    # Invisible
                root.age_textinput.opacity=0    # Invisible

        CustomLabel:
            id: age_label
            text: 'age'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'middle'

        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: age


        GreenButton:
            text: 'Ok'


        GreenButton:
            text: 'Cancel'
            on_press: app.stop()
```

### Output

[image: Figure 1 - App Startup]
[image: Figure 2 - CheckBox Female Checked & Age Widgets Invisible]
[image: Figure 3 - CheckBox Male Checked & Age Widgets Visible]

Comment: Neat trick! Though, users can still "accidently" select hidden items. More functionality would be recommended.